# submenu does not display triangle icon

Tags: android, android-layout, android-optionsmenu

In one Android app I have a menu (options Menu) in my action bar that has too many items. To fix this I want to introduce submenus.
I've defined the menu as follows (changed ids and texts):

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/some_id"
        android:title="Some Text"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/some_id"
        android:title="Some Text"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/some_id"
        android:title="Some Text"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/some_id"
        android:title="Some Text>
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/some_id"
                android:title="Some Text"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/some_id"
                android:title="Some Text"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/some_id"
                android:title="Some Text"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/some_id"
                android:title="Some Text"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/some_id"
                android:title="Some Text"/>
        </menu>
    </item>
    <item android:title="Some Text>
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/some_id"
                android:title="Some Text"/>

            <item
                android:id="@+id/some_id"
                android:title="Some Text"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/some_id"
                android:title="Some Text"/>
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

When I run the app, the menu is displayed and works, but the items with submenu don't display the submenu triangle (a icon next to the text to indicate that the items is a submenu). Isn't this icon displayed by default? what I have to do to display it?

Thanks

Comment: then why not using custom layout class for that?

Comment: would you mind sharing a small screen shot?

Comment: share image for not showing icon